# How do I add information to already existing objects in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am in need of help.

I have an ArrayList full with name of clients/customers. What I want to do is to write a code so it asks me for the client name and then I type it in and if it finds it to add a phone number to the client. Once it is added if I want to print out the list the phone number will be next to that specific client.

I have 3 classes. 1 is the client class (with variables - name, address, number) and a JobManager (the whole test program with methods such ass adding a client and removing one).

This is how my adding a client looks like:

```
  public static void addClient() {

    System.out.println("Adding a client: \n");

    System.out.print("What is the name of the new client?: ");
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println();

    if (name.length() == 0) {
        boolean invalid = true;

        while (invalid) {
            System.out.println("You cannot enter a blank name for the client. ");
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid name: "); 
            name = keyboard.nextLine();

            if (name.length() > 0) {
                invalid = false; 
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print("What is the client's address?: ");
    String address = keyboard.nextLine();

    boolean isDuplicate = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
        String listName = clientList.get(i).getName();
        String listAddress = clientList.get(i).getAddress();

    if (listName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)
                && listAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(address)) {
            isDuplicate = true;

        if (listName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            isDuplicate = true;

        }
    }

    if (isDuplicate) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Error, that client already exists! \n");
        isDuplicate = false;

    } else {

        Client client = new Client(name, address);
        clientList.add(client);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Client has been added. \n");

      }
    }
 }
```

And this is what my client class looks like:

```
public class Client {

    private ArrayList<JobManager> jobManager;
    private ArrayList<TelephoneNumber> telephoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private static int number;

    public Client(String name,String address) {

        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;     
    }

    // public void createNumber() {
    //  TelephoneNumber teleNumber = new TelephoneNumber(number);
    //  telephoneNumbers.add(teleNumber);

    //}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public static int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result;

        result = name + "\n" + address;

        result = (this.getName() + "\t" + this.getAddress());

        return result;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the answers guys!

Comment: Whats your problem ?

Comment: I just don't know how to add a phone number to a specific client existing in the list.

Comment: You have a list of phone numbers in `Client`, but no method to add one. Don't you think that it would be helpful to add a method for adding phone numbers to a `Client` instance?

Comment: Where exactly you want to add the telephone number, when you add a new Client or when they already exist in the list?

Comment: Where they already exist @robin.

Comment: @Cryphiss how to you want to check whether the client already exists using name or both name and address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a small sample of the code from your example where I am hard `enter code here`coding Telephone numbers and in the main method am hard coding 2 as am entering the user input as V3 in my test scenario.

**Client Class**

```
public class Client {

private  String name;
private List<String> telephoneNumber;

Client(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public List<String> getTelephoneNumber() {
    return telephoneNumber;
}

public void setTelephoneNumber(List<String> telephoneNumber) {
    this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    Client c = (Client)obj;
    return this.name.equals(c.name);
}
```

**TestClass**

```
public class HelloWorld{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
    Client c1 = new Client("V1");
    Client c2 = new Client("V2");
    Client c3 = new Client("V3");
    Client c4 = new Client("V4");

    clientList.add(c1);
    clientList.add(c2);
    clientList.add(c3);
    clientList.add(c4);

    HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
    h.addTelephone(clientList);

    Client cTest = clientList.get(2);
    System.out.println(cTest.getTelephoneNumber());





}
public void addTelephone(List<Client> clientList)
{
    System.out.print("What is the name of the new client?: ");
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    Client c = new Client(name);
    if(clientList.contains(c))
    {//Client Already Exist
        int i =  clientList.indexOf(c);
        Client c1 = clientList.get(i);
        List<String> telNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
        getTelephoneNumbers(telNumber);
        c1.setTelephoneNumber(telNumber);
    }

}
}
public  void getTelephoneNumbers(List<String> telephone)
{
    boolean isExit = false;

    while(!isExit)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Telephone Number  or 0 for exiting : ");
        String telp = keyboard.nextLine();
        if("0".equalsIgnoreCase(telp)) {
            System.out.println("Exiting");
            isExit = true;
        }
        else {
            telephone.add(telp);
        }
    }
}
```

you can use the same sort of addTelephone number method.

Comment: It did clear some things but I am using user input way for adding the telephone numbers.

Comment: @Cryphisss can you please show the code you have done for user inputting the telephone number ?

Comment: This is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/K1Fdn54V
It compiles but it doesn't add anything.

Comment: added the code with the method for user inputting the telephone number

Comment: Let me test. Give me a few minutes to process what you did and see how it works. Will mark you as a solution if it works! <3

Comment: Okay now I understand how you have thought about this. Went through the code compiles buuut I am in a infinite loop when I write a phone number (Where it says Enter telephone number or 0 for exiting)

Comment: are you sure you are entering zero for exiting.
Also you can use some other string like exit or something to avoid the confusion.I have tested it, it working fine.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5rj25y what I get :/ Do I have to type 0 after every time I enter a number?

Comment: Clients can have more than 1 number. Also when I print the client from the arraylist does it print out the telephone number as well with it?

Comment: if you need a client to enter more than 1 number you need a loop, thats why I am using that one, when  a client added all his numbers, he have to press 0 to exit the loop and all the numbers entered will be added to the client.

To Print the list of telephone numbers you have to modify your toString method in client class and add something like         result = (this.getName() + "\t" + this.getTelephoneNumber());

Answer (score 0):

You could do it over here:

```
if (listName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)
            && listAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(address)) {
        isDuplicate = true;
        do {
            TelephoneNumber phoneNumber = ..;//ask user for phone number and keep repeating until user enters 0 as one user can have multiple numbers

            clientList.get(i).addNumber(phoneNumber);
        } while (!phoneNumber.getNumber().equals("0"))


    //if (listName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) { //removed duplicate conditions
      //  isDuplicate = true;

    //}
}
```

And in your Client class add the addNumber to add numberi n list as :

```
public void addNumber(TelephoneNumber phoneNumber) {
    telephoneNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: Found this pretty useful. Still working on the code. Will mark it as a solution once its working!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add phone number to specific client first you have to search that client in databse:

```
public Client searchByName(String name){// find one client and return client;}
```

and then set number:

```
public void addNumber(int number){ Client client=searchByName(); client.setNumber(number);}
```

Comment: Um what? This is not close to legal Java syntax.

Comment: what?they're 2 method in a class;what's the problem?maybe it's the search method; i didn't write it completely;it must send query to data base and find 1 client;and then set its number

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addNumberToClients(String clientName, TelephoneNumber number) {
    clientList.stream()
        .filter(client -> client.getName().equals(clientName))
        .forEach(client -> client.addNumber(number);
}
```

This will add the number to all clients with the given name. To add it to just one, change `.forEach()` to `.findFirst().ifPresent()`

Then add a method to `Client`

```
public void addNumber(TelephoneNumber number) {
    telephoneNumbers.add(number);
}
```